# Reading h5 file and storing the video in that file in .avi format

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, video-capture, h5py

I am trying to read a video stored in file with .h5 extension and than store that video in a video file(.avi,.mp4).
I am able to read the data in h5 file and display video on my screen.(cv2.imshow)
But not able to write the data in a video file.
I am using cv2.VideoWriter for the purpose of writing video.
I have tried using different video format as input parameter 'VideoWriter'.It is not working
Here is the code that I have used:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*format)
#File to be read
#It is a gray scale video of mouth region extraacted from a coloured video of full face
my_h5_file = 'Z:/sa.h5'
feature_name = 'sequence'

#to read the h5 file
with h5py.File(my_h5_file, 'r') as f:
    #roi: contains the value or the video
    roi = f[feature_name].value
    #numframe  193 , y =36, x = 36
    num_frames,y,x = roi.shape[:3]

    print(num_frames)
    print('y:',y,'x:',x)
    #Using VideoWriter to write video in avi format
    outvid = cv2.VideoWriter('Z:/output10.avi',fourcc,30,(x,y))

#to write the video frame by frame
    for i in range (num_frames):
        frame = roi[i,:]
        f = np.squeeze(frame)
        outvid.write(frame)
    outvid.release()
```

It is showing this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (image->depth == 8) in
 CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG_proxy::writeFrame, file
 C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_ffmpeg.cpp,
 line 274 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "Z:/VSR/pyVSR/display_roi_video.py", line 38, in <module>
     outvid.write(frame) cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_ffmpeg.cpp:274:
 error: (-215) image->depth == 8 in function
 CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG_proxy::writeFrame
```

Comment: What is the dtype of frame? (frame.dtype)

Comment: This is the link to one of the h5 files :https://drive.google.com/file/d/17P6uhVcO1g0KiBEpZLvZroXqB-REESWS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: dtype of frame is float32.

Comment: Shape is (155,36,36,1), so you have 155 frames with 36x36 Pixel right? (It looks like cv2.VideoWriter is only accepting uint8 in your configuration. Try f=np.array(f*255,dtype=np.uint8) and in the next line outvid.write(f). The factor of 255 stands for the scaling, because it looks like that your values are in a range from 0 to 1.

Comment: Yes the file has 155 frames with 36x36 ixels.I did what you suggested.It is still giving me same error.@max9111.                                             
In my code, format = 'XVID',(used in line 1 of the code).Could that be causing any problem?

Comment: I am not familiar with cv2, but yes try various codecs, or as a first try without compression and also try np.int8 dtype.  Sorry, I thought it would be easier to solve, becuase the error message looks quite like a dtype problem...

Comment: I am able to read the video.Just not able to write it.Is there any other way I could write the file in a video format.